# Forgotten Root Password FreeBSD - Have sudo accounts

Tags: freebsd

This is a really stupid question. Is there a way of resetting the root users password on my FreeBSD machine? I have a user which has sudo capabilities so I can perform all admin functions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

No worries. We've all been there.

```
sudo passwd root
```

Comment: Ha ha thanks, for some reason I didnt think it wouldve been that easy! Thanks :)

Comment: If you're not failing, you're not trying hard enough.

Comment: This response really should be marked as "answered".